# Cisco IOS: Service Config

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

For Cisco routers/switches, I use the `no service conifg` in production.

What's the impact for the production system if I use the `service config` command when I have the configuration already loaded in my devices?

```
%Error opening tftp://255.255.255.255/cisconet.cfg (Timed out)
%Error opening tftp://255.255.255.255/cbrvbc01-tgobc02-confg (Timed out)
%Error opening tftp://255.255.255.255/cbrvbc01.cfg (Timed out)
%Error opening tftp://255.255.255.255/network-confg (Timed out)
%Error opening tftp://255.255.255.255/cisconet.cfg (Timed out)
```

Security? Network traffic? Others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `service config` command is used to load configuration files on boot.  It should have no impact to your current configuration unless you reboot.

It's worth noting that even Cisco considers configuration autoloading an [unneeded vulnerability](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=99029&seqNum=2).  It's [default is off](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/ffun_r/frf007.html#wp1017913), and probably for good reason.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly reply. But if I reboot the device, what's the impact it actually is?

Comment: @user2647545 [Cisco Support](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/49683-serviceconfig-error-msgs.html#error-msgs) indicates that these are standard config files.  Can I ask what your reasoning behind using them is?

Comment: We configure the router with `no service config` command, but for some unknown reason, it shows `service config` after about 10 min. When we save the running config to the startup config file, it will show out in our production system. Just want to know what's the real problem this will cause in the production system.

Comment: @user2647545 The `boot host` command has this guidance: _"Use the service config command to enable the loading of the specified configuration file at reboot time. Without this command, the router ignores the boot network command and uses the configuration information in NVRAM. If the configuration information in NVRAM is invalid or missing, the service config command is enabled automatically."_  What is your configuration register set to? (`show version | include register`)

Comment: AA2#show version | i register
Configuration register is 0x2102

Comment: If I load the router with `service config` setting, the error messages will shown as in my question even though it already loaded the configuration file(startup config file) from the router.

Comment: Under the `service config` in the IOS commands manual says:  If you do not specify host or network configuration filenames, the router uses the default configuration files. The default network configuration file is network-confg. The default host configuration file is host-confg, where host is the hostname of the router. If the Cisco IOS software cannot resolve its hostname, the default host configuration file is router-confg.

Comment: @user2647545 If `service config` is present in the configuration with no `boot network` or `boot host` statements, it will attempt to autoload the default TFTP adddresses.

Comment: Yes, that's what we know and ask the question: what's the real impact in the production system?

Comment: @user2647545 There isn't any real impact if your systems don't frequently reboot.